# Setting the value of `this` with `apply()`

Tags: javascript

I don't understand why this code logs "Hello world":

```
var log = function(){ console.log(this) }
var greeting = function(){ return "Hello world" }
greeting.apply(log)
```

From what I gather from the MDN page on `apply()`, calling `apply(log)` on `greeting()` sets `greeting()`'s `this` to `log()`, is that right? If that's so, why does the above code log "Hello world"?

Comment: In your code you are applying `log` to greeting and not using `this` in greeting, so `apply` would not change `greeting`s behavior with any context.  Also applying `log` would not set the context of `this` to `log()` it would set it to `log`

Comment: I guess you type the code in JS console. JS console logs the function output. `greeting` output is `Hello world` regardless of `this`. So it logs it. `greeting()` without `apply()` will output `Hello world` too.

Answer (score 3):

`this` is a pseudo-parameter, it is passed to the function every time the function is called.

```
var person1 = { name: "John" }, person2 = { name: "Maria" };

function f (greeting) { return greeting + ", my name is " + this.name; }

f.apply(person1, ["hi"]) // "hi, my name is John"
f.apply(person2, ["hello"]) // "hello, my name is Maria"
```

So what happens when you call it normally, like `foo();` ?
Well, it depends, on whether you're using ["strict mode"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode) or not:

- when NOT using "strict mode", the function will receive the global object (window) as `this`.
- when using "strict mode", the function will receive **undefined** as `this`.

To adapt your example:

```
var log = function(){ return "this is log func";  }   
var greeting = function(){ return "Hello world: " + this(); }
greeting.apply(log) // "Hello world: this is log func"
```

The above example works, because `this` is set to the *log* function. Since `this` is actually *log*, you can play around like you are doing with any other function:

```
var log = function(){ return "this is " + this.name;  }   
var greeting = function(){ return "Hello world: " + this.apply({name: "Mark"}); }
greeting.apply(log) // "Hello world: this is Mark
```

Answer (score 1):

> From what I gather from the MDN page on apply(), calling apply(log) on
>   greeting() sets greeting()'s this to log(), is that right?

No, not really. It sets sets `greeting`'s `this` to `log` ... without the parentheses. So `log` will never get called.

Additionally, `apply` also executes the function it is called on. So in your case, `greeting.apply(log)` just executes the function `greeting` and sets `this` for this function to `log`. But since you don't use `this` within `greeting` it doesn't even matter what `this` is.

Answer (score 0):

I thought i would expand my comment with an answer. Javascript's `apply` and `call` are both methods of `Function.prototype` to set the context of the keyword `this` to a given object.

For Example.

```
 var log = function() { console.log(this); };
 log() // this would `console.log` window or the global object
 log.call({example: "value"}); // Object {example: "value"}
 log.apply({example: "value"}) // same thing, but you can pass an array of arguments
```