# what is the difference between normal function and a function inside an object

Tags: javascript

What is the difference between a normal function and a function inside an object in JavaScript? Which one is best to use and how do both of these work?

What I mean is something like this:

```
var a={
    funct:function(){
        // ...
    }
}
a.funct();

function funct() {
    // ...
}
funct();
```

Comment: Simply, function of an object has access to the internal state of the object.

Comment: Well, one is a function on an object, the other is a function not on an object. There's no *fundamental* difference between them. Technically *every* single function is a function on *some* object. Please clarify what's confusing you here.

Comment: They're both inside an object.

One is `window.funct`

The other is `window.a.funct`

Comment: oh, my ..., do you see the difference between object and method?

Comment: @mic4ael *Any* function can *potentially* have access to *any* object... depends how you call it.

Answer (score 1):

Well, there's no much difference between them.

Usually a function attached to an object is referred to as a **method**.
To be fair, a global function is attached to the global object (window), so it might be considered a method of the global object (think of `alert` which is actually `window.alert`).

Not all functions are attached to objects, you can have local functions the same way you can have local variables.

```
function f () {
  var x = 12;
  var log = function (value) { console.log(value); };

  log(x);
}
```

One important difference between them would be the value of `this`, which is a pseudo-parameter passed to the functions when they are invoked, regardless if they are methods or not.
If the function is linked to an object, `this` will point to the respective object when called using the method syntax:

```
var myObject = {
   name: 'Joe',
   myFunc: function () { console.log(this.name); }
};

myObject.myFunc(); // will receive myObject as this and therefore will print "Joe"
```

However, a "normal" function will either receive the global object (window) or **undefined**, depending on whether you're using the strict mode or not (by default you're not, so **this** will point to window).

```
function f () { console.log(this.constructor); }
f(); // function Window()
```

Another answer regarding the value of `this` can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29732498/setting-the-value-of-this-with-apply/29732691#29732691) (full disclosure: I'm the author of that answer as well)

Answer (score 0):

A "function inside an object" is called a "method". It has the key difference that it can access other properties inside the object using `this`. So it's typically intended to somehow manipulate or retrieve data from the object.

In contrast, a function outside an object is usually designed to work independently outside of any particular context.

The above is quite simplified, as commenters were quick to point out. I doubt if this is the right forum for an extended tutorial on the deeper meaning of `this` or how to call functions with alternative contexts or having functions inside objects which are independent of the context of that object.

Comment: yep, it's not an answer. The question was about difference, but you just gave explanation of term

Comment: Sure, let's get all technical and confuse the OP with `apply` and `call`, or while you're at, don't forget to throw in the ES7 proposal for binding syntax of `::foo.bar()`, that ought to keep him confused for a while.

Comment: @vladkras Odd comment, the word "difference" appears explicitly in the second sentence of my answer.

Comment: The workings of `this` are one of the fundamental things you need to understand about Javascript... if you're going to explain anything at all, you will quickly have to explain `this` as well...

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a different, all functions are inside an Object, starting from the root window object. I usually use functions inside an object just to make my code more organised, readable and making use of using 'this' to access the current Object properties, thats all.